# Why Must I create a ContextLoaderListener with SpringForm?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I was trying to get spring form to work, I am using spring mvc only, When ever I try to add the spring form tag with a `modelAttribute` it fails and says that no `ContextLoaderListener` was found.

this is my JSP code for creating the form:

```
<sf:form method="POST" cssClass="form-horizontal" modelAttribute="companySearch">
```

and here is how i find my beans and my mvc is annotation-driven

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.mubasherjson.controllers" />
<context:annotation-config />
<bean id="companySearch" class="com.mubasherjson.models.CompanySearch" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

and this is my code of the post method

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String showResultPage(Model model){
        model.addAttribute(new CompanySearch());
        return "result";
    }
```

I also tried it with @ModelAttribute annotation but still nothing works, I also added the action attribute to the form but still no luck, my root path of this method is "/"

why must I create a ContextLoaderListener here ? basicly the CompanySearch is a Model and its a simple POJO, If I remove the form or comment it everything works fine. what seems to be the problem here, I've checked various questions here but still don't get it in my case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Bootstrap listener to start up Spring's root WebApplicationContext.
>   Simply delegates to ContextLoader.

[**Doc**](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/context/ContextLoaderListener.html)
It is a servlet listener called by container. Which creates application context and loads the XML bean definition files. It means everything starts with it and have to have it.

You can define it by

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
```

ContextLoaderListener Vs DispatcherServlet

In Spring MVC, there are two context. One is the application context or global context which is booted up by ContextLoaderListener. It takes all the configuration file mentioned in contextConfigLocation parameter.
Now if you are are using Spring MVC also than Dispatcher servlet is required, which boots up another container which is also known as web application container. This container takes the global container as a parent.
If you are using Spring in the backend only, then the global context is good enough. However if you are using Spring MVC also for front end than you need Dispatcher Servlet also.

(Copied from http://www.coderanch.com/t/516563/Spring/DispatcherServlet-ContextLoaderListener, I am too lazy and there is already lots of stuff out there)

Comment: well yes I saw that, but I mean I already have a context xml file for dispatcher servlet which loads bean the way i mentioned, why does the spring form need it ?

Comment: Without the `ContextLoaderListener`, the Spring container never gets started. Somehow, it must be triggered to start; for a web application, you achieve that by configuring a `Listener` that is notified by the Servlet container when the web application starts or stops.

Comment: @Developer106: For Spring MVC Dispatcher servlet is required. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Does this mean I must have the two contexts ? because right before i added the spring form tag element, everything was working fine with only the dispatcher servlet context.

Comment: @Developer106: Yes. contextloaderlistenrer will suffice unlee and until you use Spring MVC stuff like form. For MVC you need dispatcher servlet.

Comment: well that sort of answered my question, it cleared things for me thanks.